# Multiprocessing with multiple arguments to function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, program-entry-point

I'm trying to implement multiprocessing to speed up a replication loop, but cannot get it to work in Python27. This is a very simplified version of my program, based on the docs and other answers here at SO (e.g. [Python multiprocessing pool.map for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)). I realize that there are a number of quesions on multiprocessing, but so far I haven't been able to solve this issue. Hopefully I haven't overlooked anything too trivial.

**Code**

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(g, h, i):
    return g + h + i

def helper(args):
    args2 = args[0] + (args[1],)
    return func(*args2)

pool = Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.map(helper, itertools.izip(itertools.repeat((2, 3)), range(20)))
print result
```

This works when using `map(...)`, but not when using `pool.map(...)`.

**Error message:**

```
Process PoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program_\EPD_python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _
bootstrap
self.run()
File "C:\Program_\EPD_python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Program_\EPD_python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 85, in worker
task = get()
File "C:\Program_\EPD_python27\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'helper'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding a `main()` function as:

```
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(g, h, i):
    return g + h + i

def helper(args):
    args2 = args[0] + (args[1],)
    return func(*args2)

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.map(helper,itertools.izip(itertools.repeat((2, 3)), range(10)))
    print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Based on the answer from @ErikAllik I'm thinking that this might be a Windows-specific problem.

**edit**: Here is a clear and informative [tutorial on multiprocessing](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) in python.

Comment: Yes, see "Safe importing of main module" under http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: Ah, right: now I remember; I've run into this myself—this problem only happens on Windows, also with "normal" Python :) But even on OS X/Linux, it's still semantically correct to **not** put top-level code into modules that are about to be imported; which is implicitly the case when using `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fork of `multiprocessing` called [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) (*note: use the version on github*) that doesn't need `starmap` or helpers or all of that other stuff -- the map functions mirror the API for python's map, thus map can take multiple arguments. With `pathos`, you can also generally do multiprocessing in the interpreter, instead of being stuck in the `__main__` block. `pathos` is due for a release, after some mild updating -- mostly conversion to python 3.x.

```
  Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 30 2013, 20:15:49) 
  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5566)] on darwin
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool    
  >>> pool = ProcessingPool(nodes=4)
  >>>
  >>> def func(g,h,i):
  ...   return g+h+i
  ... 
  >>> p.map(func, [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
  [12, 15, 18]
  >>>
  >>> # also can pickle stuff like lambdas 
  >>> result = pool.map(lambda x: x**2, range(10))
  >>> result
  [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
  >>>
  >>> # also does asynchronous map
  >>> result = pool.amap(pow, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
  >>> result.get()
  [1, 32, 729]
  >>>
  >>> # or can return a map iterator
  >>> result = pool.imap(pow, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
  >>> result
  <processing.pool.IMapIterator object at 0x110c2ffd0>
  >>> list(result)
  [1, 32, 729]
```

Answer (score 1):

On my OS X, with Python 2.7, your code outputs:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

I can see your Python paths contain `EPD_python27`, so maybe try using a vanila Python distribution, not Enthought Python Distribution.

**UPDATE**: Please see @fileunderwater's answer for a solution; I've run into this once myself, but had totally forgotten about it :)

Explanation: The problem happens (only on Windows for some reason, but could as well be happening on OS X and Linux) because your module contains top-level code. What `multiprocessing` does is that it imports your code in the subprocess and executes it. However, if your module contains top-level code, it will be evaluated/executed immediately as the module gets imported. Wrapping it in `main` and only calling `main()` conditionally (i.e. with a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block), you're preventing this from happening. Also, this is more correct on OS X and Linux, and is generally always preferred over putting code right in the module.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Since you got it to work I tried something different and main(), which seems to solve the problem. I initially ran the program through Ipython, but with a main it works both through IDLE and at cli (still using Enthought).